# How to add System.Drawing.Image object to Asp:Image Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

How to add System.Drawing.Image object to Asp:Image Control  but I dint have imageId in my table.Image field is in another table..i retrieve image from database in Image object.i want  to display it in asp:Image control or grid view.how to do it?? pls send reply... C#

Answer (score 2):

The `Image` class and `<asp:image>` control are completely different thing.
You need to have a page or http handler to write the `Image` object as an image file such as .jpg / .png / .gif. And then use the `<asp:image>` control to access the URL of your page or http handler to get the image file you generated and display it. `<asp:image>` basically only render a HTML `<img>` tag with the URL of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this ASP.NET module](http://imageresizing.net) and [the SqlReader plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins) to serve images directly from the database.

You can then reference the images like so:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/sqlimages/[imageidhere]" />
```